# How can I make HTML code non-execute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I want to do is allow the user to input a string then display that string in the web page inside a `div` element, but I don't want the user to be able to add a bold tag or anything that would actually make the HTML text bold. How could I make it so the text entered by the user does not get converted into HTML code, if the text has an HTML tag in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a neat little function to sanitize untrusted text:

```
function sanitize(ht){ // tested in ff, ch, ie9+
  return new Option(ht).innerHTML;
}
```

example input/output:

```
sanitize(" Hello <img src=data:image/png, onmouseover=alert(666) onerror=alert(666)> World");

// == " Hello &lt;img src=data:image/png, onmouseover=alert(666) onerror=alert(666)&gt; World"
```

It will achieve the same results as setting `elm.textContent=str;`, but as a function, you can use it easier inline, like to run markdown after you sanitize() so that you can pretty-format input (eg. linking URLs) without running arbitrary HTML from the user.

Comment: Very creative, I like it. Thank you :)

Comment: This one is the best because you can insert it anywhere in the html. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use createTextNode(value) and append it to your element(Standard solution) or innerText(Non standard solution) instead of innerHTML.

For a JQuery solution look at Dan Weber's answer.

Comment: Ok, I will try that! Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: note that not all browsers support innerText, use $.text() if possible.

Comment: Noted. Thanks dandavis!

Comment: This is actually for a Chrome extension,  so it should work, but I'll play it safe ;)

Answer (score 1):

use .text() when setting the text in the div rather than .HTML. This will render it as text instead of html.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.

  $("#change-it").click(function() {
    var userLink = $('#usr-input').val().replace(/.*?:\/\//g, "");
    $('#users-text').text(userLink);
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr-input">
<br>
<button id="change-it" type="button">Update Text</button> 
<br>
<div id="users-text"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use `.text()` ?

```js
$('#in').on('keyup', function(e) {
    $('#out').text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="in">
<br>
<div id="out"></div>
```